# Installation problem of oracle java 8

Tags: java

How to move move the extracted folder of jdk-8u20-linux-x64.tar.gz in to  /usr/lib/jvm while installing oracle java in ubuntu 14.04.?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I install Sun/Oracle's proprietary Java JDK 6/7/8 or JRE?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/56104/how-can-i-install-sun-oracles-proprietary-java-jdk-6-7-8-or-jre)

Answer (score 1):

Using a PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

and then

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-set-default
```