# NetBeans not working after update

Tags: software-installation, java, openjdk, jdk, netbeans

I have been usigng [NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/) 2 years now and have encountered an issue. After a normal apt-get upgrade NetBeans stopped working altogether. After this I reinstall the JRE and JDK to no avail. However, after reinstalling NetBeans it would open but with the following error:

```
The JDK is missing and is required to run some NetBeans modules Please use the --jdkhome command line option to specify a JDK installation or see http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqRunningOnJre for more information.
```

After reading though the post I discover`/usr/local/share/java/` does not exist. Is there any way to restore the files and if not how may I resolve the issue?

I have tried the solution suggested in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/640939/installation-problem-of-oracle-java-8/640945#640945), it has no effect other than a different error message for one project.

```
Not all requested modules can be enabled: [StandardModule:org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.persistence.kit jarFile: /home/MY_HOME/netbeans-8.1/java/modules/org-netbeans-modules-j2ee-persistence-kit.jar, StandardModule:org.netbeans.modules.maven.kit jarFile: /home/MY_HOME/netbeans-8.1/java/modules/org-netbeans-modules-maven-kit.jar, StandardModule:org.netbeans.modules.debugger.jpda.kit jarFile: /home/MY_HOME/netbeans-8.1/java/modules/org-netbeans-modules-debugger-jpda-kit.jar, StandardModule:org.netbeans.modules.hibernate jarFile: /home/MY_HOME/netbeans-8.1/java/modules/org-netbeans-modules-hibernate.jar, StandardModule:org.netbeans.modules.java.kit jarFile: /home/MY_HOME/netbeans-8.1/java/modules/org-netbeans-modules-java-kit.jar, StandardModule:org.netbeans.modules.form.kit jarFile: /home/MY_HOME/netbeans-8.1/java/modules/org-netbeans-modules-form-kit.jar, StandardModule:org.netbeans.modules.spring.beans jarFile: /home/MY_HOME/netbeans-8.1/java/modules/org-netbeans-modules-spring-beans.jar]
```

Comment: How did you install the JDK?

Comment: I used [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-java-on-ubuntu-with-apt-get) tutorial when I first started with Ubuntu. All has been working fine up until recently.

Comment: What's the output of `sudo update-alternatives --config java`

Comment: There is only one alternative in link group java (providing /usr/bin/java): /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java
Nothing to configure.

Comment: You have only a JRE installed. Use this answer: http://askubuntu.com/a/640945/367165 to install the JDK

Comment: The solution in the linked answer has the effect, that you have now a installed JDK.

Comment: It did not work, I have edited the question with the new error message. Only one project gave me that error, the rest maintain message when i tried to open them.

Comment: `sudo chown -r "$USER":"$USER" ~/netbeans-8.1`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31635/discussion-between-matthew-sid-van-der-bijl-and-a-b).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, you have to install a JDK, because you said in your comments:

> There is only one alternative in link group java (providing /usr/bin/java): /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java Nothing to configure.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-set-default
```

Now you have to configure Netbeans to use this JDK or run Netbeans with

```
netbeans --jdkhome /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
```